# Having a tooltip on a specific sub-image of a main image not using a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls, tooltip

I currently work on a wpf application where I need to have little pictograms giving some extra information thanks to a tooltip. It works "fine" but it is very very very annoying. I use a canvas containing my main image and I add to its children the list of pictograms...

I am looking for a new solution, that would let me add these pictograms on my main image (a bitmap for example) using graphics and where I could assign a specific tooltip to each pictogram.

Is it possible? If no, is there any solution without the use of canvas??

(If you need more information, or if I am not clear enough, just ask me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is step-by-step solution. Please let me know if it works for you.

Create test solution with the structure shown in the image:

[image: SolutionStructure]

In MainWindow.xaml put PictoControl:

```
<Window x:Class="PictoWithToolTipSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:PictoWithToolTipSample="clr-namespace:PictoWithToolTipSample" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <PictoWithToolTipSample:PictoControl/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code for PictogramViewModel:

```
public class PictogramViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _imageSourcePath;
    public string ImageSourcePath
    {
        get { return _imageSourcePath; }
        set
        {
            _imageSourcePath = value;
            RaiseOnPropertyChanged("ImageSourcePath");
        }
    }

    private string _toolTipText;
    public string ToolTipText
    {
        get { return _toolTipText; }
        set
        {
            _toolTipText = value;
            RaiseOnPropertyChanged("ToolTipText");
        }
    }
}
```

Code for PictoListViewModel:

```
public class PictoListViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PictogramViewModel> Pictograms { get; private set; }

    public PictoListViewModel()
    {
        Pictograms = new ObservableCollection<PictogramViewModel>();
        Pictograms.Add(new PictogramViewModel() { ToolTipText = "First", ImageSourcePath = "Images/01.png" });
        Pictograms.Add(new PictogramViewModel() { ToolTipText = "Second", ImageSourcePath = "Images/02.png" });
        Pictograms.Add(new PictogramViewModel() { ToolTipText = "Third", ImageSourcePath = "Images/03.png" });
    }
}
```

Code for ViewModelBase:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaiseOnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Markup for the PictoControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PictoWithToolTipSample.PictoControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:PictoWithToolTipSample="clr-namespace:PictoWithToolTipSample" mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <PictoWithToolTipSample:PictoListViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Pictograms}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSourcePath}" Margin="10">
                        <Image.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTipText}"/>
                        </Image.ToolTip>
                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the Images folder you may put any three (just for example) images with the names 01.png, etc, as shown on the image. Set Copy If Newer property for each image in their Properties.

Build and run your solution. You will see the vertical list of three images with the tooltip for each image.

This sample uses MVVM architectural pattern (very simplified though): ViewModel in form of a PictoListViewModel is set as DataContext of the View (PictoControl). PictoListViewModel consists of the ObservableCollection of PictogramViewModel's, this collection is bound as an ItemsSource for the ListBox in PictoControl. To show up certain amount of the images with their own tooltips you just need fill up the collection in PictoListViewModel. With the ObservableCollection you can make it in runtime just adding new items to the collection, the listbox will update itself automatically.

More on MVVM in [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) by Josh Smith.